# How to import .txt file with missing data?

Tags: list-manipulation, import, data-structures

I have a .txt file that looks like this (direct copy from the file):

```
8.1376   7.2490    6.4005                   3.3893e-06 5.4310e-06 1.7980e-05 1.5303e-05 
11.2834  10.1948   8.1657   32.256   68.032 3.2509e-06 3.9237e-06 8.0432e-06 5.3961e-06 
1.5350   1.1260    0.8500                   6.6665e-07 6.8028e-07 1.9302e-06 2.4867e-06 
0.9850   0.6920    0.2360    0.192    0.768 3.3890e-09 9.8610e-09 4.6064e-08 1.3044e-07 
1.5820   1.1040    0.9130   35.712   67.840 3.2341e-07 3.7886e-07 2.4787e-06 2.9939e-06
```

I'm interested in the 5th column, in which there are some missing data in some rows. When I just

```
Import["file.txt", "Table"]
```

MMA does not see the empty positions, so e.g. the first row has 7 elements, and the 5th becomes `5.4310e-06`, which is not what I want.

How can I import the data with proper structure, and extract the desired column?

Answer (score 6):

```
str = Import["file.txt", "Data"];
mat = StringSplit[
             StringReplace[str, {"         " -> " {}", "e" -> "*^"}], 
             WhitespaceCharacter ..
       ] // ToExpression;
mat// MatrixForm
```

> [image]

Comment: The `"Data"` import format is undocumented, not listed in `$ImportFormats`. The documented (and probably faster) way to do the same is to use `ReadList["test.txt", String]`.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the information.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov "Data" is not a format, if you do `Import["foo", "Data"]` it is the "Data" element from `FileFormat["foo"]`

Answer (score 4):

From your example it seems that the stringlength of a number can't be more than 10, so any number consists from 1 to 10 characters (digits, `"e"` character and the dot `"."`). Existing numbers can be separated by from one to 10 whitespaces on one line. And the last number can have no whitespace at the end. So we need to preprocess:

```
str="8.1376   7.2490    6.4005                   3.3893e-06 5.4310e-06 1.7980e-05 1.5303e-05 
11.2834  10.1948   8.1657   32.256   68.032 3.2509e-06 3.9237e-06 8.0432e-06 5.3961e-06 
1.5350   1.1260    0.8500                   6.6665e-07 6.8028e-07 1.9302e-06 2.4867e-06 
0.9850   0.6920    0.2360    0.192    0.768 3.3890e-09 9.8610e-09 4.6064e-08 1.3044e-07 
1.5820   1.1040    0.9130   35.712   67.840 3.2341e-07 3.7886e-07 2.4787e-06 2.9939e-06";

lines=StringSplit[StringReplace[str,{EndOfLine->" ","e"->"*^"}],"\r\n"|"\n"];
matrixOfStrings=StringCases[lines,Repeated[Except[" "],{0,11}]~~Repeated[" ",{1,9}]];
matrix=ToExpression[matrixOfStrings,InputForm];
%//TableForm
```

[image: screenshot]

---

**UPDATE**

Another method which allows the columns to have arbitrary width:

```
str = ReadList["test.txt", String];

Transpose[Transpose[
   PadRight[Characters[str], Automatic, " "]] /. {c : {" " ..} :> Table["\t", Length[c]]
    , "e" -> "*^"}]
ToExpression[StringJoin /@ DeleteCases[SplitBy[#, # === "\t" &], {"\t" ..}] & /@ %]
MatrixForm@%
```

(output is the same)

Comment: And how to do it from a file? I.e., how to `Import["file.txt"]` to obtain your `str`?

Comment: @corey Use `str=Import["file.txt","String"]`. Note that on Windows in my code you may be should replace `"\n"` with `"\r\n"`.

Comment: @corey979 I've updated the answer so it should work both under Windows and Linux.